# Add Confirmed/Unconfirmed filter on Magento admin Customer Grid

Tags: magento, filter

I need to add a filter that for customers with a confirmed/unconfirmed login in the admin customer grid.

I can use this to find customers and ask them to please confirm their registration by clicking the confirmation link sent in mail on registration.

[image: scr shot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `confirmation` attribute to achieve this. Keep in mind that you'll have to implement customer rendered that does something like following:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    return is_null($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex())) ? 'Confirmed' : 'Unconfirmed';
}
```

You'll also have to implement custom filter callback for that column in order to have it filterable. :)

Comment: Ok going to check this